# Power counter on Intel processor or GPUs

Tags: gpu, counter, cpu, intel, intel-pmu

Anyone has any experiences on power counters on Intel processors(intel performance counter management library) or GPUs, which type of CPUs and GPUs support such counters, how accurate are these counters? Do such counters needs special motherboard?

Comment: There are some system counters in Intel CPU, used by powertop and other tools like https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor#pcm_power and https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/09/19/using-performance-monitor-in-analyzing-application-power-consumption-0. They need no special motherboard. To check their accuracy you may use watt-meter device on 12V power lines "EPS12V" (4 or 8 pin separate connector on motherboard to power CPU), and also record power of whole computer either on external power or with using of special PSU with builtin  wattmeter.

Comment: And there are RAPL PMU *"Intel Running Average Power Limit (RAPL)
       energy consumption counters. This is a socket-level set of counters
       which reports energy consumption in Joules"*: https://lwn.net/Articles/569674/ http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/rapl/ http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libpfm_intel_rapl.3.html